# Arduino: union/struct attribute returns the wrong value

Tags: c, memory, struct, arduino, unions

I'm trying to use a union and struct to represent a 32-bit signal that is going to be sent via a 433Mhz radio transmitter. I have a problem with getting the Arduino to store the 26-bit remote id on the signal.parts.remote attribute. When I fetch the value after setting it to 23607301 (decimal) I get 14341 (decimal) instead. How should I construct this union to have it return the correct value?

Signal.h

```
union signal_union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned unit   :2;
        unsigned channel:2;
        unsigned status :1;
        unsigned group  :1;
        unsigned remote :26;
    } parts;
    unsigned long data;
};

typedef union signal_union Signal;
```

structtest.ino

```
#include "Signal.h"

Signal signal1;
Signal signal2;

void testPassingStruct(Signal *variable)
{
    variable->parts.status = 1;

    Serial.print("Unit: ");
    Serial.println(variable->parts.unit);
    Serial.println("Should be: 2");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Status: ");
    Serial.println(variable->parts.status);
    Serial.println("Should be: 1");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Remote: ");
    Serial.println(variable->parts.remote);
    Serial.println("Should be: 23607301");
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Data: ");
    Serial.println(variable->data, BIN);
    Serial.println("Should be: 01011010000011100000000101110010");
    Serial.println("");
}

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    signal1.parts.remote = 23607301;
    signal1.parts.unit = 2;
    signal1.parts.group = 1;
    testPassingStruct(&signal1);
}

void loop() 
{
}
```

Output (from Arduino):

```
Unit: 2
Should be: 2

Status: 1
Should be: 1

Remote: 14341
Should be: 23607301

Data: 1110000000010100110010
Should be: 01011010000011100000000101110010
```

This is a follow up question on [Arduino: cannot pass union struct as pointer ac I can with gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055234/arduino-cannot-pass-union-struct-as-pointer-ac-i-can-with-gcc-compiler)

Comment: A hex calculator is your friend.  14341 = 0x3805, 23607301 = 0x1683805.  When you are looking at numbers, try looking at their hex representation as well.  Sometimes it helps in spotting such problems.

Comment: Thanks, that made it even clearer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue has to do with the fact that `unsigned` (aka `unsigned int`) is 16 bits wide. Try changing the `remote` field to `unsigned long`:

```
unsigned long remote :26;
```

Comment: Thanks did it, so simple once you know it! :)